# Canvasjs, allow single selection of data point

Tags: canvasjs

In a pie chart, is it possible to explode only one data point at a time?

Right now it will explode (move out) all clicked items in pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

Ashutosh,

You can try this:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
 {
        
      data: [
      {
        type: "pie",//"doughnut"
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55},
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14}
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

chart.options.data[0].click = function(e){    
    var dataSeries = e.dataSeries;
    var dataPoint = e.dataPoint;
    var dataPointIndex = e.dataPointIndex;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < dataSeries.dataPoints.length; i++){
        if(i === dataPointIndex){
            dataSeries.dataPoints[i].exploded = true;            
        }else        
            dataSeries.dataPoints[i].exploded = false;            
    }
    
    
    chart.render();
};

 chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
```